# How to style a dashboard with CSS in dash and python?

Tags: python, css, web-applications, plotly-dash

I don’t know much about CSS and I need help aligning these 4 smaller graphs under this larger graph. This is the closest I’ve come to being aligned.
I need the 4 smaller graphs to be aligned under the larger graph, but covering the whole page, how to do that?

[image]

my code:

```
fig_pick = px.pie(map_pick, values='Total', names='Map', title='Mapas com mais Picks no Valorant Champions 2022')
fig_pick.update_layout(margin=dict(l=40, r=25, t=45, b=20), height=300,  width=340 , template='darkly')

fig_ban = px.pie(map_ban, values='Total', names='Map', title='Mapas com mais Bans no Valorant Champions 2022')
fig_ban.update_layout(margin=dict(l=40, r=55, t=45, b=20), height=300,  width=340 , template='darkly')

fig_atk = px.bar(map_side, x='Map', y='Atk Wins', color='Map', title='Taxa de Vitórias nos mapas no lado de ataque pelo Valorant Champions em %:', 
            labels={
    'Atk Wins': 'Vitórias no lado de Ataque em %',
    'Map': 'Mapa'        }, text='Atk Wins')

fig_atk.update_traces(textposition='inside',texttemplate='%{text:.3s}')
fig_atk.update_layout(margin=dict(l=40, r=55, t=45, b=20), height=300,  width=360 , template='darkly')

fig_def = px.bar(map_side, x='Map', y='Def Wins', color='Map', title='Taxa de Vitórias nos mapas no lado de defesa pelo Valorant Champions em %:', 
            labels={
    'Def Wins': 'Vitórias no lado de Defesa em %',
    'Map': 'Mapa'        }, text='Def Wins')

fig_def.update_traces(textposition='inside',texttemplate='%{text:.3s}')
fig_def.update_layout(margin=dict(l=40, r=55, t=45, b=20), height=300,  width=360 , template='darkly')


app.layout = html.Div(children=[

        dbc.Row([

                dbc.Col([

                        dbc.Card([
                                
                                 html.H5('Opcões'),
                                 dcc.Dropdown(opcoes, value = 'ACS' , id='check_opcao', style={'width': '100%'}),
                                 
                        ],style={'height': '94vh', 'margin': '20px', 'padding': '20px', 'width': '300px'})

                ], sm=2),

                dbc.Col([

                        dbc.Row([dcc.Graph( id='grafico_gc_players', style={ 'width': '1100px'})], style={ 'margin': '20px', 'margin-right': '70px'}),
                        dbc.Row([
                                dbc.Col([dcc.Graph(id='map_pick', figure=fig_pick)], sm=3),
                                dbc.Col([dcc.Graph(id='map_ban', figure=fig_ban)], sm=3),
                                dbc.Col([dcc.Graph(id='map_side_atk', figure=fig_atk )], sm=3),
                                dbc.Col([dcc.Graph(id='map_side_def', figure=fig_def )], sm=3)
                        ])

                ],sm=10)
        ])
```

Comment: You cannot put the four graphs under the upper one because the width of the fours are larger. You can do the opposite, which is enlarging the size of the upper graph to cover the entire width of the lower four graphs. What do you think?

Comment: I encourage you to do that with bootstrap, which is easier. Please have a look at the first example https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/layout/